# Android - add Google account programmatically to non-Google device such as Nook

Tags: android, accountmanager, nook

I have a code in my app that prompts user to add Google account if one is missing.

```
AccountManager accountMgr = AccountManager.get(mContext);
accountMgr.addAccount("com.google", "ah", null, new Bundle(), 
    (Activity) mContext, null, null);
```

This works as intended on any "Google-enabled" device, however on NOOKColor code executes with no error or warning however Account Manager never starts since UI for it is probably missing. Can you think of any good alternative? All I need is to obtain AUTH token for the user's Google account to be able to access Google Reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. The `AccountManager` is just a facade, there needs to be an actual Google account implementation. You get this only on 'Google experience' devices with Market/Play pre-installed.

If you need to get a token for a Google API service, you can use the APIs directly BTW, "ah" is for App Engine, not Reader.

Comment: The Web APIs: ClientLogin, OAuth, etc. Details here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can use this since I'm targeting Reader which does not appear at list of services in client console

Comment: You should be able to get token using client login. Examples: http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/Authentication

Comment: No way I'm collecting names/pwd for Google - that pretty much guarantees many single star ratings on the market, no I have to stick with OAuth

Comment: You can get an OAuth token as well. Might be a bit trickier to integrate in your app though.